# Non-serializable values in navigation state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I'm finding it impossible to resolve this warning. I'm passing my list item as a param to the subsequent navigation screen "details" in order to display information about the user selected string from a list. I understand that I am passing a react object read"params.coinID.$$typeof (Symbol(react.element))", but I'm unable to find the proper methodology for passing this user selected parameter.

```
        <SafeAreaView style ={styles.container}>
        <Text style ={styles.title}>New Hot Tokens</Text>
        <FlatList
        data={listItems}            
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}
        onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate('Details', {coinID: (item)
              }); 
            }}  
        >{`${item.key}`}</Text>}/>
        </SafeAreaView>
  );  
}

function DetailsScreen({route, navigation}) {

const { coinID } = route.params;

console.log(coinID.key)

const { loading: coinLoading, error, data: coinData } = useQuery(COIN_INFO, {
          variables: {
                  coinForQuery: coinID.key},
                  pollInterval: 15000,
                  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
                  notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
  }
);
```

Comment: Why don't you store the function in the screen where you navigate and pass some prop to invoke it? Can you share a snack I will help you to resolve the issue?

Comment: Ah, because I'm passing the selection the user makes from the flatlist to the next screen so it knows what to render. Is there something I can use besides (item) that is navigation friendly?

Comment: Sorry I cannot tell anything without snack repro.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted in the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state

> If you don't use state persistence or deep link to the screen which accepts functions in params, then the warning doesn't affect you and you can safely ignore it. To ignore the warning, you can use `YellowBox.ignoreWarnings`.

But the general solution(without using `Redux` ) is to use `Context` API to store data in the parent Component.

Please follow this tutorial for help: https://dev.to/emeka/state-management-in-react-native-using-context-14no

Comment: No offense, but linking the doc page to the error that I described isn't super helpful, especially since I described how I was aware that I was doing something inherently wrong with how I was passing the object.

Comment: What if you encounter a problem where you need to provide a parameter that is not serializable? It's good that you figured out to pass the key in this case. But a "general answer" as I mentioned in the answer is to use context api.